# Can i have a dynamic parent in ncyBreadcrumb?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router

This is my `index.route.js` and I want my parent property to be dynamic like when the user clicks on it then it should display confirm prompt before changing state.

```
.state('user.edit', {
  url: '/{id}/edit',
  params: {
    id: {value: 'new'}
  },
  templateUrl: 'app/user.html',
  controller: 'EditUserController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  ncyBreadcrumb: {
    label: 'Add/Edit User',
    parent: 'user.list'  //(this one i want dynamic)
  }
})
```

Please help me.

Comment: Why such weird requirement?

Comment: Stack Overflow is there to fulfill our requirements. so can't say like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen the the `$stateChangeStart` event, and prevent it if the user choose to cancel it. In your controller:

```
vm.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){ 
    console.log(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options); // Here you can see what parameters are passed to the event callback function
    if( !confirm('are you sure?') ) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

BTW - `vm` is the `$scope` - not sure how you reference to it in your controller.

You can also bind it to the `$rootScope` inside the application's `run()` phase - This way you can detect state changes on a global level, and not just inside a specific sate. You will use the `toState.name` to know which state you're gooing and `fromState.name` to know the name of the sate you're leaving.